# Perform room upsert unsing rxjava on Android

Tags: android, rx-java, android-room, upsert

How to perform a database upsert using Room and Rxjava?

I have this BaseDao class

```
@Dao
public abstract class BaseDao<T> {


    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    public abstract long insert(T obj);


    @Update
    public abstract void update(T obj);


    @Transaction
    public void upsert(T obj) {
        long id = insert(obj);
        if (id == -1) {
            update(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

How do I convert it to call the upsert method using Rxjava?

Comment: what do you mean using rxjava?

Comment: @Blackbelt when I want to do an insert using Rxjava I modify my insert to Single<Long> insert(T entity). I want to do the same for the upsert method